# No results when search term include '(' in codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to search string using CI model. Here is the code written for it.

```
$test_name = "TSH ( Thyroid stimulating harmone)";
$this->db->like('test_name',$test_name);
```

Above query when executed gives me zero result. But if I change my database column and replace '(' by '{' or something else then it shows results by executing above code.

```
new $test_name variable becomes "TSH { T..."}.
```

But the requirements is to use the string containing '(' only.

How should i carry forward?
Please do let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `like()` will help you much with your search needs. you use a `where()` function containing with `LIKE` clause.

```
$keyword="TSH ( Thyroid stimulating harmone)"; 

$this->db->select('*')->from('table')->where("column LIKE '%$keyword%'")->get()->result_array();
```